# How to change user's role to admin ion mongodb

Tags: mongodb, e-commerce

How to change user's role to admin on mongodb
I have already created my collections in MongoDB, and set up products list and users but I want to make possible for only one person who is the admin to Add products to the collection and manipulate the stock quantity but I didn't find how to do that

I want some help about the issue that I am confronting

Comment: This question is probably better suited for a different site. Sounds like you want most users to have a 'read' role. [Roles in MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#database-user-roles)

Comment: Are you talking about a database user or an application user?